# switching elements between the array

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of n elements and I want to write a function to switch elements between the array like this :

1 2 3 ---> 3 1 2 ---> 2 3 1 ---> 1 2 3

I can't think of an easy algorithm to do this. Please help. This is not homework.

Comment: If you are just rotating the array - why? Just provide an interface to access the array that can cope with modular indexing. i.e. can start anywhere in that array and go back to zero when necessary.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly reasonable, if somewhat simple, question. There are valid reasons for wanting to rotate an array in place.

Answer (score 1):

Use a queue instead of a list. Enqueue the dequeued item for each step.

Another alternative is to use a circular buffer. Just keep the array as is and have a pointer to the first element, move the pointer on each step. Read the array in two phases. 1. From the pointer to the end. 2. From the beginning to the pointer.

A third alternative is to just swap element one by one.

```
int tmp = arr[0];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
{
    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
}
arr[arr.Length - 1] = tmp;
```

Comment: I think you have a bug here. You can see it if your array length is 2. In that case, code inside the loop will never be executed and your array will have the same value in `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`. Your loop control should be either `i < arr.Length - 1` or `i <= arr.Length - 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to rotate the array?

```
  // Rotate left
  int temp = a[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < a.Length-1; ++i)
    a[i] = a[i+1];
  a[a.Length-1] = temp;

  // Rotate right
  int temp = a[a.Length-1];
  for (int i = a.Length-1; i > 0; --i)
    a[i] = a[i-1];
  a[0] = temp;
```